# Nginx configuration issues

Tags: web, nginx, web-application

I need nginx to serve a certain location for a certain directory request, for example:

```
localhost/this_site
```

to serve

```
/path/to/this_site
```

How can I make that work?

Comment: so when someone goes to `http://localhost/this_site` you want to serve the contents of `/path/to/this_site`?

Comment: Exactly right!!

Comment: If my answer solved your problem you should mark it accepted by clicking the green checkmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the location (This post about [nginx, django, and gunicorn](http://senko.net/en/django-nginx-gunicorn/) has a good introduction).

```
server {
    ... your server code here ...
    location /this_site/ {
        root /path/to/this_site;
    }
}
```

Should do what you're looking for.